# Open Source Image Hosting or File Sharing website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, open-source

I would like to know if there are any free open source or paid software for hosting images (like tinypic.com imageshack.us) or file sharing (4shared.com or rapidshare.com) developed in ASP.NET.

And If I have to develop the same, how do I remove the 2 gb limit on upload in IIS?

This question contains both programming as well as non programming question.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Upload limit isn't development...it's server related. Voted to move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

[xigla](http://www.xigla.com/afilesend/features.htm) is an ASP.NET solution for a rapid share site.

[Another link aggregation site](http://asp.software.informer.com/download-asp-file-sharing-templates/) with promising links.

[Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Pages/Default.aspx) is very good too.

[Nuke Transfer](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=14107) is a file sharing module for DotNetNuke.

For most of these solutions the **file size limit is from the actual IIS config** not from the software.  **[Chris Bunk](http://www.chrisbunk.com/archives/2005/05/overcoming_iis.html)** describes a method for modifying IIS config to **allow uploads bigger than 2 gigabytes**.

Comment: Set in the web.config, with a max actually determined by the virtual address space of the IIS worker process.

Comment: Yes, but I believe that limit in the web.config is subject to the limit in the metabase.  I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Amazon S3.  It has a webservice interface which should be usable in ASP though I have no experience with that.  It is very reasonably priced, very stable, and the webservice is rock solid once you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) uses ASP.NET but it's not open source.

You probably will need to create some sort of external program (.Net, Java or Flash) to upload files larger than 2 GB. Alternatively, you can create browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file that is larger than 2 GB. If you want to upload files that total more than 2 GB, separate the files, and then upload them in batches that are less than 2 GB.

Please note that browsers has a 2GB limit as well. http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

If you 'really' need over 2GB file upload http facility, I would suggest to create an OCX component or an application, which split file internally before uploading to server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find 2 sites for you

1. [ASP.net Image galleries](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/asp-net/scripts-controls/image-galleries/) has a list of open source scripts for image management
2. [I-Load](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/i-load-2008/)

The upload sie is not programming related as others said.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested out [Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/) before. It's a very nice image gallery solution with loads of built in functionality. It's also capable of hosting thousands of images, the only real limitation is the hard disk you have it sitting on.

But the 2gb limit is from the server side as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) - an open source web based photo album organizer. You can have as many Galleries as you want on your web server and each gallery can contain as many photo albums as you want.